# Parsing @font-face via regex PHP

Tags: php, regex

I know it already sounds bad but this is one of those tasks where I am forced to do things that I dont like thus I am asking for help. **Please take a min to look at it. Yes I have looked trough everything that you might suggest like CSS parsers , regex snippets around stack but this is specific case. I hate it as much as you do but I must finish it.**

I need to parse the CSS file , get all @font-face kits, place them in an array with a key that consists out of the `font-family` and `font-weight`.

**So desired format is this**

```
    array
(
    [montserat400] => array
    (
        [font-family] => ''montserat''
        [src] => 'url('montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff')'
        [font-weight] => '400'
        [font-style] => 'normal'
    )
    [montserat500] => array
    (
        [font-family] => ''montserat''
        [src] => 'url('montserrat-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff')'
        [font-weight] => '500'
        [font-style] => 'normal'
    )
)
```

This is the CSS

```
/*! Generated by Font Squirrel (https://www.fontsquirrel.com) on March 25, 2018 */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserat';
    src: url('montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserat';
    src: url('montserrat-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserat';
    src: url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserat';
    src: url('montserrat-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserat';
    src: url('montserrat-extrabold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Among other things that I have tried, this is what currently works

```
$re = '/@font-face.*{\K[^}]*(?=})/';
preg_match_all($re, $css, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

if($matches){

    $parsed = array();

    foreach($matches as $k => $ff ){

        $css    = $ff[0];
        $attrs  = explode(";", $css);

        foreach ($attrs as $attr) {
           if (strlen(trim($attr)) > 0) {
              $kv = explode(":", trim($attr));
              $parsed[$k][trim($kv[0])] = trim($kv[1]);
           }
        }

        unset( $attrs );            
    }
    print_r($parsed);

}
```

and it gives me this which is usable and I can do another loop and set the keys the way I like

```
array
(
    [0] => array
    (
        [font-family] => ''montserat''
        [src] => 'url('montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff')'
        [font-weight] => '400'
        [font-style] => 'normal'
    )
    [1] => array
    (
        [font-family] => ''montserat''
        [src] => 'url('montserrat-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff')'
        [font-weight] => '500'
        [font-style] => 'normal'
    )
    [2] => array
    (
        [font-family] => ''montserat''
        [src] => 'url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff')'
        [font-weight] => '600'
        [font-style] => 'normal'
    )
    [3] => array
    (
        [font-family] => ''montserat''
        [src] => 'url('montserrat-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff')'
        [font-weight] => '700'
        [font-style] => 'normal'
    )
    [4] => array
    (
        [font-family] => ''montserat''
        [src] => 'url('montserrat-extrabold-webfont.woff') format('woff')'
        [font-weight] => '800'
        [font-style] => 'normal'
    )
)
```

but it simply seems like I am doing to much for this and using 3 loops with same data seems wrong.

Comment: You can parse it using a tokenization method, here is an example https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/JasonDecoder.php  This was made for Json Objects, unqoted JSON, I could write one up for you but alas I have to leave work.  Your data structure is about 1000x easier... lol

Comment: You can get rid of the last loop you suggest (to make the keys you want) by building the key in your inner foreach loop. `if (trim($kv[0]) == 'font-family') { $font_family = trim($kv[0]); }` etc.

Comment: Nothing wrong with loops, just depends what you do in those loops and what you loop over.

Comment: @Shane I cant wrap my brain around it , that was the actual idea

Comment: @Benn It's honestly not that big of a deal which way you go. Just use the extra loop, it will probably be more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL; DR

```
$matches = preg_split('~(?>@font-face\s*{\s*|\G(?!\A))(\S+)\s*:\s*([^;]+);\s*~', $text,
    -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
# index counter
$i = 0;
$output = [];
# PHP 7 doesn't change internal pointer, hence passing by-ref
foreach($matches as $key => &$match) {
    # Check if we're reaching end of block
    if (strpos($match, "}") !== 0) {
        # Storing current value as key, next as value
        $output[$i][$match] = $matches[$key + 1];
        # Skip over next value off iteration
        unset($matches[$key + 1]);
        continue;
    }
    # Increment index counter
    $i++;
}

print_r($output);
```

**[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/ZGC7j)**

Using `\G` token, you are able to go through all properties and their values at once. You may either do a match or split. I preferred the latter:

```
(?>@font-face\s*{\s*|\G(?!\A))(\S+)\s*:\s*([^;]+);\s*
```

[**RegEx live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zy8dkw/2)

Breakdown

- `(?>` Start of non-capturing group

  - `@font-face\s*{\s*` Match a font-face block
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Continue from where last match ends
- `)` End of NCG
- `(\S+)` Match and capture property name
- `\s*:\s*` Match a colon
- `([^;]+)` Match and capture value
- `;\s*` Match a ; and trailing spaces if any

Comment: kiss your brain for that regex :). So we still have to use another loop for the desired output right?

Comment: Check [this demo](https://3v4l.org/OJiaC). You have an array as an output. You may work with that array or you may want to do a loop to make your own format. You could achieve same results with two regexes if you don't like loops. But I don't recommend. @Benn

Answer (score 1):

I did it with two capturing groups one for the key and the other for the value. and with one `foreach` to assing keys and values

```
$re = '/^(.*):\s*(.*)\s*;$/m';
$matches = array();

preg_match_all($re, $css, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$parsed = array();
$count = 0;

foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
    if ($count === 0) {
        $tmp = array();
    }

    $tmp[trim($match[1])] = trim($match[2]);

    if ($count === 3) {
        $parsed[] = $tmp;
        $count = 0;
    } else {
        $count ++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($parsed);
echo "</pre>";
```

Gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'montserat'
            [src] => url('montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff')
            [font-weight] => 400
            [font-style] => normal
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'montserat'
            [src] => url('montserrat-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff')
            [font-weight] => 500
            [font-style] => normal
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'montserat'
            [src] => url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff')
            [font-weight] => 600
            [font-style] => normal
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'montserat'
            [src] => url('montserrat-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff')
            [font-weight] => 700
            [font-style] => normal
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'montserat'
            [src] => url('montserrat-extrabold-webfont.woff') format('woff')
            [font-weight] => 800
            [font-style] => normal
        )

)
```

Comment: not bad but see this , https://regex101.com/r/jbTtCN/1

if the CSS is compressed does not seem like it will fetch it